# Automatic content resizing of JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, docking, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to create an app with a `JLayeredPane` that scales automatically with the size of the parent `JFrame` (this is the easy part using `BorderLayout` as layout manager on the frame's content pane). The hard part is the fact that I want the content of the `JLayeredPane` to automatically resize with the `JLayeredPane` (and thus the `JFrame` too).

In fact the functionality I want to achieve is a lot like the dockable console in Netbeans, that just like comes "on top" of the editor when clicked, and when dismissed hides again and docks into the "console" word in the status bar. Obviously I also want resizing behavior to work correctly. What would be the best way to achieve this (if not with `JLayeredPane`)?

Comment: Funny that you mention NetBeans. Should you have the option, you can build your application on top of the NetBeans API to have these features ootb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use a ComponentListener added to the JLayeredPane and have its content responds to the `void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)` method.

Comment: Does this imply the content does not scale dynamically (during resizing) but only when the mouse is released?

Comment: No, it means that content will rescale when/if you tell it to and then only when `componentResized(...)` is called. Test it.

Comment: @Warkst That's the point of the `JLayered` pane.  It has no layout manager to tell the components what to do...

Comment: This is working perfectly. @MadProgrammer, I understand the `JLayeredPane` has a `null` layout for a reason, I was just wondering what was the right way to resize the components. Thanks @Hovercraft!