# JLayeredPane with JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jlayeredpane

The problem: I have no control on implementing more into the histogram package, so I create an array of buttons and overlay them on top of the histogram using JLayeredPane. However, I cannot get both the histogram plot and the buttons panels to scale when the JFrame is enlarged or contracted.
The JLayedPane is composed of 2 JPanels, see MWE.

To repeat the issue, just run program and extend JFrame.

I have read the following on SO posts; [jlayeredpane-with-gridlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838076/jlayeredpane-with-gridlayout), [jlayeredpane-with-a-layoutmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334874/jlayeredpane-with-a-layoutmanager), [jlayeredpane-not-resizing-with-jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522151/jlayeredpane-not-resizing-with-jframe), [resize-jframe-to-jpanels-inside-jlayeredpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804626/resize-jframe-to-jpanels-inside-jlayeredpane), [automatic-content-resizing-of-jlayeredpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755083/automatic-content-resizing-of-jlayeredpane),
as well as the [Oracle page on JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) which has some examples

As useful as these links were, I still cannot get both JPanels to extend/contract with the JFrame.

Question: Is there a way to get both JPanels in the JLayeredPane to rescale without implementing a new layout? If  new layout is needed, would someone please provide a MWE on how to do such?

```
public class FrameDemo extends JPanel {

    private JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    private final int width = 800;
    private final int height = 800;
    private String[] layerStrings = { "Yellow (0)", "Magenta (1)", "Cyan (2)", "Red (3)", "Green (4)", "Blue (5)" };
    private Color[] layerColors = { Color.yellow, Color.magenta, Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue };

    public FrameDemo() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        init();
        addPanels();
        add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void init() {
        this.layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        this.layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Histogram should go here"));
        this.layeredPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    }

    private void addPanels() {
        this.layeredPane.add(createHistogramPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER, new Integer(1));
        this.layeredPane.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER, new Integer(0));
        this.layeredPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            Dimension size = layeredPane.getSize(); // get size
            createHistogramPanel().setSize(size); // push size through
            createButtonPanel().setSize(size); // push size trhough
            // otherChildOfLayers.setSize(size); // push size trhough
            layeredPane.revalidate(); // revalidate to see updates
            layeredPane.repaint(); // "Always invoke repaint after
                                    // revalidate"
        }
    });
    }

    private JPanel createHistogramPanel() {

        JPanel histpanel = new JPanel();

        histpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < layerStrings.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[i], layerColors[i]);
            histpanel.add(label);
        }
        histpanel.setOpaque(false);
        histpanel.setBounds(10, 10, width, height);
        return histpanel;
    }

    private JLabel createColoredLabel(String text, Color color) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(color);
        label.setForeground(Color.black);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 120));
        return label;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            final int placer = i + 1;
            JButton freshButton = new JButton();
            freshButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                System.out.println("Button " + placer + " clicked");
            });

            freshButton.setText("Button " + (i + 1));
            freshButton.setOpaque(true);
            freshButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            freshButton.setBorderPainted(false);
            freshButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(132, 75 + (i * 20), 40, 20));
            buttonPanel.add(freshButton, null);
            buttons.add(freshButton);

        }
        buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);

        buttonPanel.setBounds(10, 10, width, height);
        return buttonPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new FrameDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest to remove the first paragraph and the one about jars from your question. It adds nothing to understand the specific problem.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522151/jlayeredpane-not-resizing-with-jframe
As you already mentioned this one, what is different with your problem?
Could the answer proposing to update the size with a listener for `componentResized` be a suitable solution for you as well?

Comment: I did try the solution on the post ,i.e addComponentListener,  you mentioned, but it did not solve the problem. That is why I did not include it into the MWE. I edited my MWE to show that this solution does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work because in `componentResized` you're creating *new* panels and applying the size to them. You need to resize the *existing* panels added to the layered pane. This could be done by assigning `histogramPanel` and `buttonPanel` as instance variables.

Comment: I also tried making them instance variables and I had luck solving the problem that way.